# Turn 2 hash tables into one without losing the order of keys

Tags: perl

I am trying to do something I figured would be quite simple, but it seems I'm either missing a letter or something or I just don't know how to do it properly.
I have  2 hash tables with values.
e.g (written in simple code just to illustrate the hashes! I know how the syntax looks in the code):

```
%hash1=>(key1,key2,key3)=>[value1,value2,value3]
%hash2=>(key4,key5,key6)=>[value4,value5,value6]
```

I want to merge the two, so that I'll have one hash, with these keys & values (order matters).

```
%hash3=> (key1,key2,key3,key4,key5,key6) =>[value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6]
```

I tried using [`Hash::Merge`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::Merge), but it failed. I tried to slice the hash:

```
(@Hash1{ keys %Hash2 } = values %Hash2)
```

because I thought it'll just add it to "the bottom" of the list. It doesn't seem to work.

I am beginning to think, it's adding them by the time they were created, and they're created sort of in this order:
value4,value5,value1,value2,value6,value3

So possibly, that's why it does it... however... I want to avoid the option to loop over each hash once after it's done to just add it one by one... is there any option other than that? (The script runs for less then 0.1 second, so it's fine either way, but I want the code to look ok as well as work properly.
Thanks.

Comment: Hashes have no innate ordering for keys. You apply order to keys based on how you sort the extracted keys, or you have the keys stored in an array or list, and you have applied some desired sort order to that array.

Comment: afaik it's actually a feature, that hashes are (not anymore) allowing the prediction of the order of their keys.

Comment: The code you posted is not valid Perl. Please use a package like `Data::Dumper` to display data structures.

Comment: @shawnhcorey from my comment below: "Thanks, I know the syntax I used in the post isn't correct, I was just illustrating what I want the order to be..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hash keys don't have a fixed order. To keep elements in a specific order, you can use for example an array, or maybe a module like [`Tie::IxHash`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::IxHash) or [`Tie::Hash::Indexed`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::Hash::Indexed) (as suggested by @daxim, thanks) - but see below in regards to these modules.

However, personally I find that in most cases, instead of keeping the hashes in a certain order using additional modules, just [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html)ing on output is enough:

```
my %hash1 = (key1=>'value1', key2=>'value2', key3=>'value3');
my %hash2 = (key4=>'value4', key5=>'value5', key6=>'value6');
my %hash3 = (%hash1, %hash2);
for my $key (sort keys %hash3) {
    print "$key: $hash3{$key}\n";
}
```

Output:

```
key1: value1
key2: value2
key3: value3
key4: value4
key5: value5
key6: value6
```

See also the FAQs [How do I sort a hash (optionally by value instead of key)?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-sort-a-hash-(optionally-by-value-instead-of-key)%3f) and [How can I always keep my hash sorted?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-always-keep-my-hash-sorted%3f).

Here is a `Tie::IxHash` example, the output is the same as above; note how the `sort` isn't needed. `Tie::IxHash` will preserve the order in which elements were added to the hash - *but* please be sure that this is what you want, because it's *not* the same as sorting the keys on output, as I showed above - the modules remember insertion order, while the `sort` solution will sort the keys for output only, without changing anything in the original hash. Using `tie`d hashes will also cause a performance impact.

```
use Tie::IxHash;
tie my %hash1, 'Tie::IxHash';
tie my %hash2, 'Tie::IxHash';
tie my %hash3, 'Tie::IxHash';
%hash1 = (key1=>'value1', key2=>'value2', key3=>'value3');
%hash2 = (key4=>'value4', key5=>'value5', key6=>'value6');
%hash3 = (%hash1, %hash2);
for my $key (keys %hash3) {
    print "$key: $hash3{$key}\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know the syntax I used in the post isn't correct, I was just illustrating what I want the order to be... Thanks for the thorough explanation, I will check this out.

Comment: [Tie::Hash::Indexed](http://p3rl.org/Tie::Hash::Indexed) is faster than Tie::IxHash.

Comment: @MoreE: While I respect your choice of answer, I am certain that it would be best to code your own solution. Both `Tie::IxHash` and `Tie::Hash::Indexed` seem like a godsend if they do *exactly* what you want, but they don't carry with them any explanation of what you intended and why, and there is too much *action at a distance* for comfort. At the very least your code needs to include comments about the *order of the source data* as well as *why you want to retain the same order* for other purposes. This is a very non-Perlish application of hashes, and you should reconsider your solution.

Comment: @haukex: The OP says very clearly in the question that the order they require is ***not*** the order of creation. Your solution will ensure that the order is always wrong, while dramatically increasing run time. Questions that are based on misconceptions like this are only confounded further by answers who treat those misconceptions seriously. I shall flag your answer for removal, but I hope you see fit to do the surgery yourself.

Comment: @Borodin *"The OP says very clearly in the question that the order they require is not the order of creation."* Sorry, but that's not my understanding of the question - it gives a very clear example of sample input with expected output. I take the *"I am beginning to think, it's adding them by the time they were created"* to be an attempt at understanding *why* the hash was output "out of order", and *not* the *desired* order. I'm not sure what other misconceptions you are talking about. I'll make an edit in regards to `Tie::IxHash`, but I'm not sure what other "surgery" you mean.

Comment: @hauk: The input is far from clear; it is over-simplified to two static hashes of strings. For the OP to expect them to be ordered I guess that the real data came from two separate database requests. The correct "answer" here is an explanation that neither `%hash1` nor `%hash2` were ever in any order that the OP may have imagined, and an encouragement to ask the *real* question with much wider vision. `Tie::IxHash` is very rarely a practical solution to any real-life problem, and you should at least have withheld it until you understood the question. Racing for points doesn't look good.